# Is code injection possible in R via functions that read CSVs or parse JSON from the web?

Tags: r, security, code-injection, jsonlite, api-security

Web frameworks that inadequately sanitise inputs can be prone to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).

Are R processes vulnerable to 'R injection' in the same way? That is, can someone (or some API) provide inputs to R functions (especially those that can read from the web, like `read.csv()`, `jsonlite::fromJSON()`) that cause code to be executed?

I already know that [code injection is possible in languages other than SQL](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/145394/211696), although I haven't discovered any examples in R.

I see some [examples of *SQL* injection in shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sql-injections.html), but note I am *only* interested in learning about possible *R* injections (not SQL injections).

In case it's relevant, the actual use case is an R function that reads JSON from an external API via `jsonlite::fromJSON()` - I wish to ensure that it is not possible for any JSON data (valid or malformed) to cause remote code execution within the R function. The function doesn't do anything with SQL hence why I am not so interested in SQL injection.

Comment: If you don't parse and evaluate arbitrary user input (or use functions that do so), you don't have to worry. That's one of the reasons why some contributors to the R tag constantly fight the good fight against use of `eval(parse())` (although there are other, often more important, reasons).